# WebMail.Send() throws FormatException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying `WebMail.Send()` to send mail to multiple email ids. The [MSDN library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webmail.send%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) clearly specifies that multiple email ids should be separated by semicolon(;). However when I try to send mails to multiple ids, I get `FormatException` with Message that says 
**"An invalid character was found in the mail header: ';'**. However if I send mail to single receipent, the mail gets delivered properly.

So, how do I send mails to multiple receipents using `WebMail.Send()`? Perhaps I am missing something very obvious.

Edit:
Here is the code that I am using.

```
string [] selectedUserIds = GetEmailIds();
string to = string.Join(";", selectedUserIds);
WebMail.Send(to: to, subject: subject, body: message, cc: cc, filesToAttach:   attachments, isBodyHtml:true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a documentation error. The delimiter works for `,`. This is the standard delimiter for email addresses.

See for the System.Net.Mail namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t.aspx - see the last comment.

Comment: There are no multiple from addresses. Its a single from address that I have configured in Web.Config. For code please see my question, I have edited it to include the relevant code.

Comment: I wonder if you have a rogue ; at the start or end of the variable `to`.

Comment: Valamas, the to field is properly formatted and contains entries like this "abc@domain.com;xyz@domain.com". I checked that in debugger. There is no other semicolon(;) anywhere in variable to.

Comment: Valamas, I would never have imagined that issue. Thanks to you. I can now send mails to multiple receipents.

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Net.Mail`-related classes all use `,` to seperate addresses in the To, Cc, and Bcc fields.  I suggest you change your code to look like:

```
string to = string.Join(",", selectedUserIds);
```